# Projet laravel / vuejs from linux to windows

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, routes

I try to pass my project create on linux to a windows but i got a problem.
In my project i got a DB and all is fine, i can sign in and in my table i see my account.

Now my login function in auth.js (store)

```
async login({ dispatch }, credentials){
            let response = await axios.post(`/api/auth/connexion`, credentials);
            if(!response.data.error){
                dispatch('attempt', response.data.token).then((resp)=> {
                    if(resp){
                        dispatch('message/resetState', null , {root: true});
                        router.push({ name: 'Home', query: {category: 'home'} });
                    }
                });
            }else {
                dispatch('message/setError', response.data.error , {root: true});
            }
        }
```

And my dispatch('attempt', response.data.token) ;

```
async attempt({ commit, state }, token) {
            if(token){
                commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
            }
            if (!state.token){
                return
            }
            try{
                let response = await axios.get(`/api/auth/me`);
                commit('SET_USER', response.data);
                response = await axios.get(`/api/auth/isAdmin`);
                commit('SET_ADMIN', response.data);
                return true;
            }
            catch(err){
                commit('SET_TOKEN', null);
                commit('SET_USER', null);
                commit('SET_ADMIN', null);
            }
        }
```

If i console.log token in is printed, but ir the :

```
await axios.get(`/api/auth/me`)
```

Don't works and i found why, it's because my method login and signin is in except middleware :

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
```

My question is :

Why my auth middleware is not setup and not work ??

This project work fine on my other pc on linux.
Thanks for help !

Comment: `$request->user()` it means login `user()` so if u don't apply `auth` middleware  then it will consider public uses that url and didn't found `auth()`

Comment: yes is what i told myself for that error, i update question more clearly.